# DHCP Server Performance Testing with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, dhcp

I want to test a Router (DHCP Server),that means I  want to test the Performance of the DHCP Server (Router), in other words, when a  someone want to have access to the internet, his device get an IP address from this Router (DHCP Server).
I found a Load driver in form of a Linux Workstation which  simulate multiple DHCP clients, (device,PC,Smartphone), but it works only on Centos OS

my question is how to implement this Test with Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

As of JMeter version [5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) there is no official support of the DHCP protocol via [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/).

So the only way of implementing the test you're looking for is using i.e. [dhcp4java library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp4java/) from [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), but you will have to write [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) code representing your use case yourself.

An example of sending a broadcast request can be found in [DHCPClient](https://github.com/ggrandes-clones/dhcp4java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dhcp4java/examples/DHCPClient.java) class.

You might also want to take a look at [DhcpClient.java from Android OS](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/31e19f3/services/net/java/android/net/dhcp/DhcpClient.java) if you need more verbose example.

Comment: I have a python script which generate IP Adresses and send it to the Router, so to give them an IP to get to the Internet, but the question is, how to implement it on Jmeter to mesure the Performance of the router..(DHCP)